# High count of unloaded classes

Tags: jvm, jaxb, jetty, classloader

I'm seeing count of unloaded classes increasing over the time.

[image]

From what I read, the classes will only be unloaded, if underlying classloader is garbage collected. So, does it mean that my jetty-based application is creating and destroying classloaders frequently?

Answer (score 1):

This legacy application is using rhino js engine. And according to this thread, default mode is to "generate classes", and in turn classloader for each request.

https://dev-tech-js-engine.mozilla.narkive.com/Aly49IOz/memory-leak-with-rhino-class-loader

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64397

The solution seems to change the optimization level for interpretive mode.